# How to lock everything for registered users in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I wish to lock everything bureaucratic (all actions, all special pages etc.) to all users without a sysop role in MediaWiki.

This is how I currently do it semi automatically.

First, I install the [extension lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown).

Then, before locking all special pages, I lock all actions because it's much easier than locking all special pages (there are about 6 actions but about 150 special pages).

To lock all actions, I put this in LocalSettings.php:

```php
$wgActionLockdown['edit'] = array( 'sysop' );
$wgActionLockdown['delete'] = array( 'sysop' );
$wgActionLockdown['move'] = array('sysop');
$wgActionLockdown['protect'] = array( 'sysop' );
$wgActionLockdown['history'] = array( 'sysop' );
$wgActionLockdown['createtalk'] = array('sysop');
```

After that, locking all special pages is ha bit hard but currently possible somewhat automatically like this:

**1)** A list of all special pages is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page

**2)** From the shell (CLUI) I download the page to stdin, match the names with grep, filter the name with sort (which also removes duplicates) and redirect the output to a txt file:

```bsh
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page -s | grep -oP 'Special:\K[a-zA-Z0-9]*' | sort -u > special_page_names.txt
```

**3)** I Use AWK to put each name in the blocking template of Extension:Lockdown:

```bsh
awk '{ print "$wgSpecialPageLockdown[\47"$0"\47] = array(\47sysop\47);" }' special_page_names.txt > special_page_names_processed.txt
```

4. I Paste the output in LocalSettings.php

---

Do you know an easier way to lock all special webpages?

Please note if you lock anything else besides actions and special pages.

Answer (score 0):

People need to be able to log in.

$wgSpecialPageLockdown['Userlogin' ] = [ '*' ] ;

Every other Special page is blocked.

$wgSpecialPageLockdown[] = array('sysop');